# Can I improve the usage time of my Li-Ion battery?

Tags: battery-life

I am using an Acer Aspire 3683 laptop, which is about to complete its 3rd birthday! It's working good but i have been contemplating over this question for quite some time before i thought of posting it here.

> My laptop battery is a 6 cell Li-Ion battery and it gives a usage time of 2 hours. Most of the laptop's which are 3 years old generally give the same usage time. The present laptops are giving a standby time of more than 4hours which makes me feel sad. My question, is there any way by which i can improve by battery usage time, or is it possible for me to replace my battery with the new batteries, so that it last more time?

Thanks! I am waiting to see some good interesting answers.

Comment: Though it might not matter for the answers: the word "backup" confuses me. Do you mean "standby time" (when *not* using the computer), or "usage time"? A standby time of 4 hours for current notebooks would be pretty bad. (Apart from that, for the short summary as displayed on http://superuser.com/questions please remove the introduction and maybe change the title into something like "Can I improve the standby time of my Li-Ion battery?")

Comment: @Arjan: Backup means the usage time!

Comment: @Arjan: Title edited

Comment: Okay, that's a better title. But why not take that confusing "backup" out of the question too? Don't count on folks reading through all the comments. The question is too long and confusing now, if you'd ask me.

Comment: @Arjan: done!...

Comment: Nice article by HP on the question...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01297640&tmp_track_link=ot_recdoc/c00817650/en_us/c01297640/loc:4&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&product=4125509

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Batteries wear out, no way around that. Once you lose performance in a battery it is gone. You can always replace a battery, but it must be the same technology type and of course must still be compatible (fit in the slot, contacts in the right spot, etc). If they offer an improved battery that is still compatible with your system, then you can use it, but chances are you are stuck with the same type of battery you've been using.
[Here](http://www.batteryer.com/Acer-laptop-batteries/Acer-Aspire-3683WXMi-battery.html) is one that might be compatible, its a 9 cell.

Comment: By the way in what manner is that one better than the one i have.

Comment: The more cells there are, the more lithium you have, the greater the charge it can hold: http://www.batteryeducation.com/2008/10/how-many-cells-are-in-a-battery.html